# Write a program that reads strings and writes them to a file

Tags: c

Here's my task, below is most of the code done and finally my specific question

Write a program that reads strings and writes them to a file. The string must be dynamically allocated and the string can be of arbitrary length. When the string has been read it is written to the file. The length of the string must be written first then a colon (‘:’) and then the string. The program stops when user enters a single dot (‘.’) on the line.

For example:

User enters: This is a test

Program writes to file: 14:This is a test

Hint: fgets() writes a line feed at the end of the string if it fits in the string. Start with a small length, for example 16 characters, if you don’t see a line feed at the end then realloc the string to add more space and keep on adding new data to the string until you see a line feed at the end. Then you know that you have read the whole line. Then remove any ‘\r’ or ‘\n’ from the string and write the string length and the string to the file. Free the string before asking for a new string.

MY CODE:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_SZ 256


int main()
{

    char key[] = ".\n";
    char* text;

    text = (char*)malloc(MAX_NAME_SZ);
    if (text == NULL)
    {
        perror("problem with allocating memory with malloc for *text");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("EX13.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("EX13.txt not opened.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter text or '.' to exit: ");
    while (fgets(text, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin) && strcmp(key, text))
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%ld: %s", strlen(text) - 1, text);
        printf("Enter text or '.' to exit: ");
    }

    free((void*)text);
    fclose(fp);

    puts("Exit program");

    return 0;
}
```

SPECIFIC QUESTION:

How can I make the program to allow arbitrarily long lines so there shouldn't be no limit at all for line length? Thanks

Comment: Use `std::getline` with `std::string`.  There are countless examples out there.

Comment: This looks like C code, not C++. The solutions for different languages would be different, so if you're really looking for a C answer you should tag appropriately.

Comment: Well, if this is supposed to be C, then here's a hint: read the hint in your question

Comment: Seeing the hint inside your question you will have to ask more specifically what got you stuck. Focus on the specific problem you had when trying to work according to the hint by your teacher.

Comment: @4386427 thats exactly his question, asked after the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a pointer to char, read char by char and keep using reallocating the pointer until you get to the '\n':

```
int main()
{
   char key[] = "."; //Excluded the \n since I'm not using fget
   char* text;

   FILE* fp;
   fp = fopen("EX13.txt", "w");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      perror("EX13.txt not opened.\n");
      return 1;
   }

   printf("Enter text or '.' to exit: ");

   int cont = 0;
   while (1) //read all chars
   {
       if(!cont) //if it is the first, allocate space for 1
           text = (char*) malloc(sizeof (char));
       else //otherwise increase the space allocated by 1
           text = (char*) realloc(text, (cont + 1) * sizeof(char));
     
       scanf("%c", &text[cont]); //read a single char
       if(text[cont] == '\n') //see if it is the end of line
       {
           text[cont] = 0; //if it is the end of line, then it is the end of the string
           if(!strcmp(key, text)) //if the string is just a dot, end the loop 
               break;
           fprintf(fp, "%ld: %s\n", cont, text);
           printf("Enter text or '.' to exit: ");
           cont = 0; //restarting the counter for the next input
           free(text); // freeing after each iteration. you can optimize to maintain the space and only increase after getting to a bigger string than the previous you had so far
        }
        else //if it is not the end of the string, increase its size by 1
           cont++;
   }

   free((void*)text);
   fclose(fp);

   puts("Exit program");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @vmp.Thanks. Only error by compiler is 'potentially uninitialized local pointer variable' text' used' in the line where realloc is. Any suggestions please?

Comment: that is probably a warning, since cont starts with 0 it will always enter the if first.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using [getline()](https://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getline/)

This seems to be a class room assignment, so I will not be writing the code for you.

Note: for the `getline()` function to be visible in linux, at the beginning of your code, you will need a statement similar to:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

or

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

getline(3)

NAME

```
 getdelim, getline -- get a line from a stream
```

LIBRARY

```
 Standard C Library (libc, -lc)
```

SYNOPSIS

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 ssize_t
 getdelim(char ** restrict linep, size_t * restrict linecapp,
     int delimiter, FILE * restrict stream);

 ssize_t
 getline(char ** restrict linep, size_t * restrict linecapp,
     FILE * restrict stream);
```

DESCRIPTION

```
 The getdelim() function reads a line from stream, delimited by the char-
 acter delimiter.  The getline() function is equivalent to getdelim() with
 the newline character as the delimiter.  The delimiter character is
 included as part of the line, unless the end of the file is reached.

 The caller may provide a pointer to a malloced buffer for the line in
 *linep, and the capacity of that buffer in *linecapp.  These functions
 expand the buffer as needed, as if via realloc().  If linep points to a
 NULL pointer, a new buffer will be allocated.  In either case, *linep and
 *linecapp will be updated accordingly.
```

RETURN VALUES

```
 The getdelim() and getline() functions return the number of characters
 written, excluding the terminating NUL character.  The value -1 is
 returned if an error occurs, or if end-of-file is reached.
```

EXAMPLES

```
 The following code fragment reads lines from a file and writes them to
 standard output.  The fwrite() function is used in case the line contains
 embedded NUL characters.

       char *line = NULL;
       size_t linecap = 0;
       ssize_t linelen;
       while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, fp)) > 0)
               fwrite(line, linelen, 1, stdout);
```

ERRORS

```
 These functions may fail if:

 [EINVAL]           Either linep or linecapp is NULL.

 [EOVERFLOW]        No delimiter was found in the first SSIZE_MAX characters.

 These functions may also fail due to any of the errors specified for
 fgets() and malloc().
```

Note: you will need to pass to `free()` the line, when the code is through with it, to avoid a memory leak.

Note: to remove any trailing '\n' you can use:

```
line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Note: after removing any trailing '\n' you can use:

```
size_t length = strlen( line );
```

To get the length of the line in bytes.

Then print that length and the line using:

```
printf( "%zu:%s", length, line );
```